# Django includes the wrong generated/compressed CSS file

Tags: django, django-templates

We intend to extend openstack's Horizon, which is a Django application. The first goal: add some custom CSS. Our approach is to create an own Django project and, in settings.py, to import Horizon's default settings ("from openstack_dashboard.settings import *"). After this import we extend the TEMPLATE_DIRS, by adding our custom template directory before the original Horizon directories. The template directory is BASE_DIR/templates. In it is the file _stylesheets.html.

This approach works well while in debug/development mode (Django delivers the correct template and CSS). But when we deploy the application with debug mode off, our custom CSS code is not included correctly. The interesting part is that Django in fact generates two CSS files: One with parts of and one without our additions. And it includes the one with parts of the custom CSS classes.

Here is the template's content:

```
{% load compress %}

{% compress css %}
<link href='{{ STATIC_URL }}bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less' type='text/less' media='screen' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='{{ STATIC_URL }}bootstrap/less/datepicker.less' type='text/less' media='screen' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='{{ STATIC_URL }}dashboard/less/rickshaw.css' type='text/css' media='screen' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='{{ STATIC_URL }}dashboard/less/horizon_charts.less' type='text/less' media='screen' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='{{ STATIC_URL }}dashboard/less/horizon_workflow.less' type='text/less' media='screen' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='{{ STATIC_URL }}custom.less' type='text/less' media='screen' rel='stylesheet' />
{% endcompress %}

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}dashboard/img/favicon.ico"/>
```

In development mode the files are converted each to CSS:

```
<link media="screen" type="text/css" href="/static/dashboard/css/bootstrap.699284425211.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link media="screen" type="text/css" href="/static/dashboard/css/datepicker.39a8e5b9c87f.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="/static/dashboard/less/rickshaw.css">
<link media="screen" type="text/css" href="/static/dashboard/css/horizon_charts.985669de17ce.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link media="screen" type="text/css" href="/static/dashboard/css/horizon_workflow.aa358dadad47.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link media="screen" type="text/css" href="/static/dashboard/css/custom.f2648785ac78.css" rel="stylesheet">`
```

In production, it looks as follows (after manage.py collectstatic and compress):

```
<link media="screen" type="text/css" href="/static/dashboard/css/571c5f6c29ad.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

<s>But it should include 6176ec592868.css.</s> *See Edit 1.* All the available css files:

```
# find generated/static/ -name "*.css"
generated/static/dashboard/less/rickshaw.css
generated/static/dashboard/css/571c5f6c29ad.css
generated/static/dashboard/css/6176ec592868.css
generated/static/horizon/lib/jasmine-1.3.1/jasmine.css
generated/static/horizon/lib/qunit/qunit.css
```

We already checked that the INSTALLED_APP and TEMPLATE_DIRS order is right (our stuff comes first). We're stuck - do you have any ideas where to look next?

**Edit 1:** I just noticed, that 6176ec592868.css in fact only contains the old CSS stuff and 571c5f6c29ad.css seems to be the incomplete CSS file with our modifications. So the question is slightly different: Why could it happen that in dev mode everything is converted to .css correctly, but that "manage.py compress" in turn does not gather all of the less files correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

horizon by default uses lesscpy (python) instead of lessc (javascript). Obviously lesscpy did not like our less code.

So we changed this:

```
COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    ('text/less', 'lesscpy {infile}'),
)
```

To this:

```
COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    ('text/less', 'lessc {infile} {outfile}'),
)
```

lessc likes our less code more and it works!